# Unable to access my inbox

Tags: support, questions

I keep getting notifications reporting "  The following item was added to your inbox since you last checked it on 2018-09-21:  "

but when I try to access the item using "http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?" link the browser merely spins until it reports it is unable to display the page.
When I try  "See all of your inbox items:" using the link
 "https://stackexchange.com/users/1187796?tab=inbox " I get the same response

I have to open stack overflow generically, then search that tag for my question. I do not see what the issue is.